# HTTP request chaining and returning promise not working

Tags: angular, promise, observable

I have a common service to make http call. 
The first http call is to get token and with the updated token the second request is made. But user will call the `doPost()` method only.
And the user should be able to resolve the promise it in the component.

```
public getToken(){
    return this.http.get(<url>);
  }

public doPost(){
       this.getToken().subscribe(token => {
          return this.http.post(<url>,token);
       });
    }
```

The post method return is not working.
How to return the promise of the second call after the first call is success.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `subscribe` twice, just use `pipe`:

```
public getToken(){
  return this.http.get(<url>);
}

public doPost() {
  this.getToken().pipe(
    mergeMap(token => this.http.post(<url>, token))
  )
}
```

now you should be able to get the answer to the `post` method:
`this.doPost.subscribe(res => <do something with the res>);`

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
import {switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators';

public getToken(){
  return this.http.get(<url>);
}

public doPost(){
  return this.getToken().pipe(switchMap(token => this.http.post(<url>,token)));
}
```

And call function `doPost().toPromise();` or `doPost().subscribe();`

Answer (score 0):

You should use an observable as well as subscribe to it. Unless you want specifically a promise, by default it is an observable and it should stay like that. Now you are not returning anything from doPost. it should be something like this:

```
public getToken(){
    return this.http.get(<url>);
  }

public doPost(){
       var result: Subscription = this.getToken().subscribe(token => {
          return this.http.post(<url>,token);
       });
    }
```

And then you can resolve this subscription and get back another observable if you want it like that.

If you want specifically a promise you "toPromise()" on an observable result.

What I would do in your place is subscribe to an observable in the class you are using the result of it and assigne a variable you use inside that class as soon as the result is back, or resolve i in the async pipe in the html part of it.

Something like this should give you a clue:

```
public getToken(){
    return this.http.get(<url>);
  }

public doPost(){
       this.getToken().subscribe(token => {
          this.yourvariable = this.http.post(<url>,token);
       });
    }
```

Or

```
<div *ngFor="let x in yourVariable | async"></div>
```